# Ошибка с работой над файлом при использовании random

Tags: python, файлы, aiogram, случайные-числа, txt

Имеется следующий хэндлер, который должен в ответ на сообщение присылать рандомную строку из файла.

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=[*types.ContentTypes.PHOTO, *types.ContentTypes.VIDEO, *types.ContentTypes.VIDEO_NOTE])
async def compliment(message: types.Message):
    f = open("Compliment_Bot\complimets.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")
    f.readline()
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text=(f.readline(random.randint(1, 500))))
    f.close()
```

Но при работе он присылает одну и ту же (почему-то вторую). В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Понял почему выводилась всегда вторая строка, потому что я нечаянно добавил лишний readline, но теперь читается только первая, как это исправить и сделать рандомный выбор строк?

Comment: Сперва прочитать все строки, а потом из них выбрать случайную

Comment: @andreymal, каким образом можно выбрать одну?(подскажи оператора)

Comment: через `readlines` прочитать все строки в список, и выбирать потом из него

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open("Compliment_Bot\complimets.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")
lines = f.readlines()
lines[random.randint(1, 500)]
```

lines - это список, а значит начинается с 0.
Еще, если `random` вернет значение значение `> len(lines)-1` будет ошибка, т.к. выйдешь за пределы списка

Answer (score 0):

Аргумент у `readline` задаёт максимальное число символов, которое будет прочитано. А читаться при этом будет всё-равно одна строка. Вам лучше использовать `random.choise`, прочитав все строки файла через `readlines`. Ну и используйте контекстный менеджер, чтобы не закрывать файл "вручную":

```py
    with open(r"Compliment_Bot\complimets.txt", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        text = random.choice(f.readlines())
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text=text)
```

Да, ещё используйте raw-string, чтобы не экранировать бэкслэши, а `"r"` можно не писать - это дефолтный аргумент у `open`.